# How To Get The Correct NodeJS Child Process.spawn Output

Tags: node.js, terminal, child-process

I am trying to run `ls -la` from NodeJS through the `child_process` module. However, when I run it, it works, but it does not give me the correct output. Instead, I get this:

[image: Program Showing the wrong output]

I expected the result to look more like this:

[image: Expected Ouput]

Here is my code:

```
const child_process = require("child_process")


function runShell(command) {
    let shellCommand = command.split(" ")[0]
    let commandArgs = command.split(" ").slice(1, command.length)
    let script = child_process.spawn(shellCommand, commandArgs)
    
    script.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
        console.log(data)
    })

    script.stderr.on("data", (data) => {
        console.warn(`Error: ${data}`)
    })

    script.on("close", (code) => {
        console.log(`Script Ended On code ${code}`)
    })
}
runShell("ls -la")
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. So what you need to do is for some reason, `console.log` for the `stdout` data does not work unless you put it in a string.
The New Code would be:

```js
const child_process = require("child_process")


function runShell(command) {

    let shellCommand = command.split(" ")[0]
    let commandArgs = command.split(" ").slice(1, command.length)
    let script = child_process.spawn(shellCommand, commandArgs)
    
    script.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
        console.log(`${data}`) # This has been changed
    })

    script.stderr.on("data", (data) => {
        console.warn(`Error: ${data}`)
    })

    script.on("close", (code) => {
        console.log(`Script Ended On code ${code}`)
    })
}
runShell("ls -la")
```

I am not 100% sure why that needs to happen for the correct output to be printed though.

## Edit:

A better solution would be to let nodejs handle all of the standard IO.
The New Code Would Be:

```js
function runShell(command){
    let shellCommand = command.split(" ")[0]
    let commandArgs = command.split(" ")
    commandArgs.shift()

    const executeCommand = spawn(shellCommand, commandArgs, {
        stdio: [process.stdin, process.stdout, process.stderr]
    })
}
```